# How to link to website base ("home page") when base tag is present?

Tags: html, base-tag

I have the following tag inside the `head` of my document:

`<base href="/some/folder/">`.

Let's say my website is at `http://example.com`. A link, like this:

`<a href="foo/bar/">...</a>`

on the page will resolve to `http://example.com/some/folder/foo/bar/`.

However, a link like this:

`<a href="/">...</a>`

will resolve to `http://example.com` when I actually want it to point to `http://example.com/some/folder/`.

In this situation, how can I create a link to the base of my application without hardcoding `http://example.com` anywhere?

Comment: Using `<a href="./">` worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `<a href="./">...</a>`  instead of `<a href="/">...</a>.`
 As pointed out by [cbroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe)